# setting arquillian on Wildfly Preview 25: NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/threads/AsyncFuture

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to run this test on Arquillian:

```
@ExtendWith(ArquillianExtension.class)
class ArquillianTest {
    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "arquillian-test.war");
    }

    @Test
    void execTest() {
        fail("Always fails");
    }
}
```

but it gets ignored and the whole execution just fails with:

```
INFO: JBoss Threads version 3.1.0.Final

Test ignored.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/threads/AsyncFuture

    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient$Factory.create(ModelControllerClient.java:609)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:121)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:179)
```

I do not think I am missing anything in my deployment method, since there are no classes involved in this simple test, but I am new to Arquillian.

I found a bug report of the same error, but it was in 2014 and apparently resolved: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jboss-jira/2014-April/256446.html

This is my pom.xml (relevant parts):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.Alpha10</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit5</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit5-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.Alpha10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.Alpha10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Alpha2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and this is my arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 5.0"/>

    <container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">C:\Users\sotan\Software\wildfly-preview-25.0.1.Final</property>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100</property>
            <property name="managementPort">10090</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

Comment: That definitely looks correct to me. Feel free to file an issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFARQ.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I just did it: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFARQ-104